# Jenkins Ansibe plugin Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Permission denied (publickey,password)

Tags: jenkins, ssh, ansible, ssh-keys

With -vvv

> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: jenkins  SSH: EXEC ssh
> -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 'IdentityFile="/tmp/ssh8563979558010522067.key"' -o
> KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o
> PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey
> -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="jenkins"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/var/jenkins_home/.ansible/cp/1db09d4d88  '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo ~jenkins && sleep 0'"'"''  (255, '',
> 'Permission denied (publickey,password).\r\n') failed: [host]
> (item={u'path': u'/srv/'}) => {
> "ansible_loop_var": "item",
> "item": {
> "path": "/srv/"
> },
> "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Permission denied (publickey,password).",
> "unreachable": true } fatal: [host]: UNREACHABLE! => {
> "changed": false,
> "msg": "All items completed",
> "results": [
> {
> "ansible_loop_var": "item",
> "item": {
> "path": "/srv/"
> },
> "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Permission denied (publickey,password).",
> "unreachable": true
> }
> ] }

With -vvvv

> SSH: EXEC ssh -vvv -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o
> ControlPersist=60s -o 'IdentityFile="/tmp/ssh3969335212632432263.key"'
> -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey
> -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="jenkins"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/var/jenkins_home/.ansible/cp/1db09d4d88 host '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo ~jenkins && sleep 0'"'"''  (255, '', 'OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u7, OpenSSL 1.0.2u  20 Dec 2019\r\ndebug1: Reading
> configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config\r\ndebug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config
> line 19: Applying options for *\r\ndebug1: auto-mux: Trying existing
> master\r\ndebug1: Control socket
> "/var/jenkins_home/.ansible/cp/1db09d4d88" does not exist\r\ndebug2:
> resolving "host" port 22\r\ndebug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv
> 0\r\ndebug1: Connecting to host [host] port 22.\r\ndebug2: fd 3
> setting O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug1: fd 3 clearing O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug1:
> Connection established.\r\ndebug3: timeout: 9997 ms remain after
> connect\r\ndebug1: key_load_public: No such file or
> directory\r\ndebug1: identity file /tmp/ssh3969335212632432263.key
> type -1\r\ndebug1: key_load_public: No such file or
> directory\r\ndebug1: identity file
> /tmp/ssh3969335212632432263.key-cert type -1\r\ndebug1: Enabling
> compatibility mode for protocol 2.0\r\ndebug1: Local version string
> SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u7\r\ndebug1: Remote protocol
> version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.6p1
> Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3\r\ndebug1: match: OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
> pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000\r\ndebug2: fd 3 setting
> O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug1: Authenticating to host:22 as
> 'jenkins'\r\ndebug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file
> "/var/jenkins_home/.ssh/known_hosts"\r\ndebug3: record_hostkey: found
> key type RSA in file /var/jenkins_home/.ssh/known_hosts:8\r\ndebug3:
> load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from host\r\ndebug3: order_hostkeyalgs:
> prefer hostkeyalgs:
> ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa\r\ndebug3: send packet: type 20\r\ndebug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent\r\ndebug3:
> receive packet: type 20\r\ndebug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT
> received\r\ndebug2: local client KEXINIT proposal\r\ndebug2: KEX
> algorithms:
> curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c\r\ndebug2:
> host key algorithms:
> ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519\r\ndebug2:
> ciphers ctos:
> chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc\r\ndebug2:
> ciphers stoc:
> chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc\r\ndebug2:
> MACs ctos:
> umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1\r\ndebug2:
> MACs stoc:
> umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1\r\ndebug2:
> compression ctos: zlib@openssh.com,zlib,none\r\ndebug2: compression
> stoc: zlib@openssh.com,zlib,none\r\ndebug2: languages ctos:
> \r\ndebug2: languages stoc: \r\ndebug2: first_kex_follows 0
> \r\ndebug2: reserved 0 \r\ndebug2: peer server KEXINIT
> proposal\r\ndebug2: KEX algorithms:
> curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1\r\ndebug2:
> host key algorithms:
> ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519\r\ndebug2:
> ciphers ctos:
> chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com\r\ndebug2:
> ciphers stoc:
> chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com\r\ndebug2:
> MACs ctos:
> umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1\r\ndebug2:
> MACs stoc:
> umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1\r\ndebug2:
> compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com\r\ndebug2: compression stoc:
> none,zlib@openssh.com\r\ndebug2: languages ctos: \r\ndebug2: languages
> stoc: \r\ndebug2: first_kex_follows 0 \r\ndebug2: reserved 0
> \r\ndebug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256\r\ndebug1: kex: host key
> algorithm: rsa-sha2-512\r\ndebug1: kex: server->client cipher:
> chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC:  compression:
> zlib@openssh.com\r\ndebug1: kex: client->server cipher:
> chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC:  compression:
> zlib@openssh.com\r\ndebug3: send packet: type 30\r\ndebug1: expecting
> SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY\r\ndebug3: receive packet: type 31\r\ndebug1:
> Server host key: ssh-rsa
> SHA256:fRV68xCwju6yze949RcpoWVhQeyehYXLtbWhWPTU1lQ\r\ndebug3:
> hostkeys_foreach: reading file
> "/var/jenkins_home/.ssh/known_hosts"\r\ndebug3: record_hostkey: found
> key type RSA in file /var/jenkins_home/.ssh/known_hosts:8\r\ndebug3:
> load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from host\r\ndebug1: Host 'host' is
> known and matches the RSA host key.\r\ndebug1: Found key in
> /var/jenkins_home/.ssh/known_hosts:8\r\ndebug3: send packet: type
> 21\r\ndebug2: set_newkeys: mode 1\r\ndebug1: rekey after 134217728
> blocks\r\ndebug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent\r\ndebug1: expecting
> SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS\r\ndebug3: receive packet: type 21\r\ndebug1:
> SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received\r\ndebug2: set_newkeys: mode 0\r\ndebug1:
> rekey after 134217728 blocks\r\ndebug2: key:
> /tmp/ssh3969335212632432263.key ((nil)), explicit\r\ndebug3: send
> packet: type 5\r\ndebug3: receive packet: type 7\r\ndebug1:
> SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received\r\ndebug1: kex_input_ext_info:
> server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>\r\ndebug3:
> receive packet: type 6\r\ndebug2: service_accept:
> ssh-userauth\r\ndebug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received\r\ndebug3:
> send packet: type 50\r\ndebug3: receive packet: type 51\r\ndebug1:
> Authentications that can continue: publickey,password\r\ndebug3: start
> over, passed a different list publickey,password\r\ndebug3: preferred
> gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey\r\ndebug3:
> authmethod_lookup publickey\r\ndebug3: remaining preferred:
> ,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey\r\ndebug3: authmethod_is_enabled
> publickey\r\ndebug1: Next authentication method: publickey\r\ndebug1:
> Trying private key: /tmp/ssh3969335212632432263.key\r\ndebug3:
> sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA
> SHA256:wTt7v+ut3bRBfNkw2IVWge8baHLD2TFiBa2LzDyVJbI\r\ndebug3: send
> packet: type 50\r\ndebug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for
> reply\r\ndebug3: receive packet: type 51\r\ndebug1: Authentications
> that can continue: publickey,password\r\ndebug2: we did not send a
> packet, disable method\r\ndebug1: No more authentication methods to
> try.\r\nPermission denied (publickey,password).\r\n')

But if I manually run the same command - all ok!

> ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o -o
> 'IdentityFile="/tmp/ssh5848573579273762009.key"' -o
> KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o
> PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey
> -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="jenkins"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 host '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo ~jenkins && sleep 0'"'"''

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I just re create ssh key credentian in Jenkins and all worked!